# Why isn't this struct getting set in a function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm trying to pass a struct pointer to a function and initialize the struct via pointer. Any idea why this isn't working?

```
struct Re
{
    int length;
    int width;
};

void test (Re*);

int main()
{
    Re* blah = NULL;
    test(blah);
    cout << blah->width;
    return 0;
}

void test(Re *t) {
    t = new Re{5, 5};
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer errors in the method of transmission(c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672816/pointer-errors-in-the-method-of-transmissionc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pointer is copied into the function, as it is passed by value. You must pass a pointer to a pointer or a reference to a pointer in order to initialize it:

```
void test(Re *&t) {
    t = new Re{5, 5};
}
```

Comment: Works great, but I'm a bit confused to the difference vs if you did this with an int. I'm new to C/C++, but I was told stucts are handled like primitive types? So why does test(int *t) work but you need test(Re *&t) for a struct?

Comment: @user2471908 You'd have to show us your `int*` code as I'm willing to bet that it's not the same as the code you have above, only changing `Re` to `int`.

Comment: @user2471908 If you were using it like this:
`void test(int* t){ *t = 0; }`
It was right because you're passing the int by reference (because you pass an `int*`), but in this case you're not trying to initialize a `Re`, you're initialazing a `Re*`, and thus you need a reference to it (`Re**` or `Re*&`)

Comment: Yes, like `void test(int* t){ *t = 0; }`. I'm confused why that works but `void test(Re* t)` wouldn't work?

Comment: `void test(Re* t)` would work only to initialize an instance of `Re` like @FlowerFire's answer, but you want to initialize a `Re*`, not a `Re`. If you want to initialize an instance of a type `T` you must pass a `T*` or a `T&`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize a pointer in your function parameter, because in your `test()` function:

```
void test(Re *t) {
    t = new Re{5, 5};
}
```

You didn't pass a reference of a pointer. Either a reference of a pointer or pointer to a pointer is required for initializing pointers objects.

You might also do:

```
int main()
{
    Re blah;
    test(&blah);
    cout << blah->width;
    return 0;
}

void test(Re *t) {

  t->length = 5;
  t->width = 5;    

};
```

Comment: This answer is plain wrong -- you're deferencing a `NULL` pointer. Furthermore, the OP wants whatever changes made to `blah` in function `test` to persist after it returns. Your code example does not do that.

Comment: @greatwolf My idea is not wrong, I still can initialize my pointer's object in my `void test(Re* t)` function (As Boris Vidolov pointed out). The thing I forget to mention is to pass a reference of a pointer for testing purpose in `main()`. But thank you for pointing out.

Comment: It would likely have been better to just leave the code sample out, as it is *still* wrong (`blah->width` won't compile).