# How to change value of arguments in the function

Tags: c, malloc

I try it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void foo(int* x)
{
   x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 5;
}

int main()
{

   int a;
   foo(&a);
   printf("%d\n",a);  //a = -858993460
   return 0;    

}
```

why the value of a != 5 . i run this code in vs2010 ,windows 7.

Comment: Because you have changed the original value of `x` in this line: `x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`.

Comment: Don't `malloc`, and don't cast the pointer in C, casting a `void *` is a C++ thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing the pointer value in foo by the malloc call - just do this:

```
void foo(int* x)
{
   *x = 5;
}
```

In your code - this function:

```
void foo(int* x)
{
   x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *x = 5;
}
```

Works as follows:

```
+----+
| a  |
+----+
/
x points here
```

Then you make `x` point somewhere else:

```
+----+                            +----+
| 5  | /* created by malloc*/     | a  |
+----+                            +----+
/ On Heap                         / On Stack
x now points here                a is now in memory somewhere not getting modified.
```

And you make it `5`. Also note - `x` is a local copy of the `&a` address of `a` - in `C` there is no pass by reference but only pass by value - since the variables value is copied into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer `x` is already initialized in formal arguments, `malloc` will create `x` pointing to another memory location.

```
void foo(int* x)
{
 /* x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); */
  *x = 5;
}
```

Please look at Acme's answer for very good diagrammatic representation.

Answer (score 1):

- `foo(&a);` Passes the address of a variable to a function.
- `void foo(int* x)` That address passed is now copied and stored in `x`. `x` is a pointer variable local to the function.
- `x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`. Here you overwrite the contents of `x` with a completely different address, to dynamically allocated memory.
- `*x = 5;` Here you assign the value 5 to that memory, which resides on the heap.
- `}` Here you forgot about everything you did in the function. You create a memory leak since you didn't `free()` the memory. Apart from that, the function has done nothing that affects the rest of the program. It only fiddled around with the local variable `x`.
- `printf("%d\n",a);` Here you print the contents of the uninitialized variable `a`, which has not been altered by the function.

In addition, it never makes sense to cast the result of malloc in C. Also, malloc is found in `stdlib.h`. Don't use `malloc.h`, that's a superfluous, non-standard header.

Answer (score -1):

In `foo`, variable `x` is a local variable, a pointer to an int - it is a variable containing a value which is the address of an `int` in memory.

You are calling the function with the address of main's `a` variable. But then you are changing x

```
x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This changes `x` to be a different value, the address of an area of memory now reserved for our use. HOWEVER, `x` is a variable local to `foo`. When `foo` ends, `x` goes away, and we return to `main`. Two things have happened:

1. We have allocated some memory,
2. We have assigned a value to it.

You then print out the contents of `main`s `a`. `a` is still at the same location it was before we called foo.

Perhaps this previous answer to a related question will help you: [Pointer errors in the method of transmission(c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672816/pointer-errors-in-the-method-of-transmissionc/19673143#19673143)