# Difference between ptr and &ptr

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple C++ program as written below:

```
void main()
{

    int *ptr;
    ptr=new int;
    *ptr=10;

    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<&ptr<<endl;
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
}
```

What's the difference between the first two statements. Both give an address. Since the new operator reserves a memory in the heap, which statement gives the address of the dynamically reserved memory in the heap, `ptr` or `&ptr`. Now if we do:

```
delete ptr;
```

This will free the memory dynamically reserved in the heap earlier but `&ptr` still points to that memory location. Why ??

I've been looking at this link for help: 
https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/lectures/slides_cpp_dynamic-memory.php

Comment: `main()` must always `return` `int` in [tag:c++]!

Comment: @Johnsyweb You put backticks around return to indicate that it's code, but in that case, your claim is wrong. It must return `int`, but it does not need a `return` statement.

Comment: I thought the standard doesnt require a return, but many compilers bitch if you have function returning a type that dont actually do a return. Thought I agree, main need to claim a return type of int. void is an unacceptable weirdness that should be stamped out.

Comment: @hvd: You're right... I should have said `main()` must always *have a return type of* `int`.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: They do, because in other functions the `return` is required. However, `main` is a special case and it is explicitly allowed by C++ to omit the `return` statement in `main`.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout<<ptr<<endl;
```

This prints out the value held by `ptr`. That corresponds to an address, in this case the address of a dynamically allocated `int`.

```
cout<<&ptr<<endl;
```

This prints out the address of the pointer itself.

> delete ptr; ... This will free the memory dynamically reserved in the heap earlier but &ptr still points to that memory location. Why ??

Because that is what `delete` does: it de-allocates whatever `ptr` points to. You can re-use `ptr` to point to something else, or set it to `nullptr`, but you have to be explicit about it. Bear in mind that many pointers can point to the same dynamically allocated memory address, so setting one of them to `nullptr` does not guarantee safety (thanks to @hvd for clarifying this part of the question).

*Note**: Pointers are "special" because they hold values which are addresses. But they also have addresses of their own, like any other variable. This may be clearer if expressed with a non-pointer type:

```
int i = 42;
std::cout << i << std::endl;  // prints value of i, i.e 42.
std::cout << &i << std::endl; // prints address of i.
```

Comment: I think the last "Why ??" is about why `ptr` isn't reset to a null pointer, or something like that. There can be any number of variables that point to the same address, so that couldn't work reliably enough to be useful, but the OP might not realise that.

Comment: Well the difference between ptr and &ptr is clear. But the issue is that "delete" is not de-allocating what "ptr" points to. For example when I print "ptr" even after doing "delete ptr", it gives the same address "ptr" points to, unless I explicitly do ptr= NULL. so why do have this "delete" at all ? why just we don't rely on NULLING it up ??

Comment: @user3054062 `delete` *is* de-allocating what `ptr` points to. That is its job. But it doesn't make `ptr` a `nullptr`, it leaves it pointing to the same place. Accessing this place would be *undefined behaviour*. So, it `ptr` is to be used after the call to `delete`, you have to either make it point to a valid location, or set it to `nullptr` (or `0` or `NULL` of you don't have C++11).

Answer (score 2):

So following gets printed :

```
cout<<ptr<<endl;  // Address pointed by ptr

cout<<&ptr<<endl;// Address of ptr

cout<<*ptr<<endl; // Value conatined in address pointed by ptr
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case(`&ptr`) you get the address of the pointer. Yes, a pointer is an object and it in turn has a pointer. So you would assign `&ptr` to a variable of type `int **`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator has at least three possible meanings:

1. When following a type name, e.g. `int &` or `int&`, it promotes the type to a reference. `int& p = q;` means p is a reference to an integer.
2. When preceeding a variable name or value it means `address of`. `int* p = &q;` means that p is a pointer to an integer, and it's value is the address of variable q (where q is an integer).
3. Bit-wise and.

So your

```
cout << &ptr << endl;
```

hits #2 and means "print the address of ptr".

Comment: Well The "ptr" and "&ptr" problem is clear but the issue which is still unresolved is that "delete" is not de-allocating whatever ptr points to, unless we do ptr = NULL. For instance I wrote the code:

void main()
{


 int *ptr;
 ptr=new int;
 

 cout<<ptr<<endl;
 cout<<&ptr<<endl;


 delete ptr;
// ptr= NULL;


 cout<<ptr<<endl;
 cout<<&ptr<<endl;
}
 and the output it gives is
0x00431810

Comment: `ptr` is a pointer, when you `delete` what it's pointing to, the pointer is unaffected. `&ptr` continues to be the address of it. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672816/pointer-errors-in-the-method-of-transmissionc/19673143#19673143). In your context, `delete` is equivalent to when they close the gate - it doesn't wipe your piece of paper clear nor take it away, but it does allow the airport to use that gate for another flight.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is pointer to the new `int` you allocated on heap.

`&ptr` is pointer to `ptr` itself which is created on stack in function call for main.

On `delete ptr` int you allocated on heap is unallocated. `&ptr` is valid, it is pointing to `ptr` pointer variable which exists on stack. You can still use `ptr` to point to something else of type `int`.