# c++ use an input argument as output

Tags: c++

This is my situation:

```
    void Database::execute(string query, Table *outTable) {

        //some code

        if (isSelect) {
            outTable = new Table(rowCount, columnCount);
        }

        // some code

    }
```

My idea is that the function execute performs a query on the db. If the query produces a table (e.g. a select), I allocate outTable.
Anyway, after the execution of this function, when I try to do something with outTable in the calling function, I get a segfault. I've already checked that the function execute the line with command new.
What's wrong here?

Here is what I do in calling function:

```
Database d = new Database("mydb");    
Table *t;
d.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", t);
int n = t->rowCount(); //here I get the segfault
```

Comment: Pass by reference? Or `*outTable = Table(...);`?

Comment: @H2CO3 I added something in the question about the function calling. Please check it.

Comment: @the_cadyman then the second version doesn't apply, and you need to pass by reference. Oh wait no, first you should read a beginner C++ tutorial.

Comment: how constructive could be this downvote with no motivation?

Comment: @the_candyman See close votes, mine came along with a downvote ...

Comment: Don't use output arguments. Just **return** the damn thing.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz what if I want to return a boolean flag or an int for error?

Comment: I come from the mathematics forum... there if one post a downvote, it comments it... so one can understand why!!!

Comment: @the_candyman Use something like `Either<value, int>` or `optional<value>` or just `throw` an exception. And I downvoted because of the XY problem you have; if you just returned a value, you'd have no problems.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz this approach sounds interesting. Can you give me some reference?

Comment: @the_candyman _'I come from the mathematics forum'_ Doesn't matter. If you're here you're here. If you're in rome behave as the romans do ...

Comment: @the_candyman I guess you should just google `optional` or haskell Maybe.

Comment: @g-makulik ok, you're right. But what can we construct if one destroys without saying anything?

Comment: @the_candyman The rules about how to ask questions here are [pretty well defined](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @g-makulik ok, but that's really a non-sense!

Comment: @the_candyman Argue this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are local variables of functions. So in your case the original pointer to Table will not be changed. Only the local variable of the function will be changed. Either pass this parameter by reference or apply one more indirection using pointers. For example

```
void Database::execute(string query, Table * &outTable);
d.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", t);
```

or

```
void Database::execute(string query, Table * *outTable);
d.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", &t);
```

Comment: thanks, you have been very clear!

Answer (score 1):

`Table *outTable` is local to the execute function, it's a copy of your variable passed in, so the Table pointer in the calling function doesn't get assigned anything inside execute.

You can verify this if you just print the address of the table pointer in the calling function and then printing the address of outTable inside execute itself (by not dereferencing the pointer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing a pointer in - input variables are local to the function. So you need to get meta and pass the address of the pointer you want to store the out value in, or use a reference (which is kinda implemented as a pointer with a contract that the language will try to make sure concrete values are passed).

That last is worth noting:

```
 bool Database::execute(const std::string& query, Table& into)
```

This will avoid copying the query into a temporary string local to execute, and will allow the caller to provide you with a Table to be populated by your function.

Having written a fair few of these, you may want to consider using a bool to indicate whether the query was successful or not, too :)

```
Table myTable;
bool success = d.execute("SELECT 'fail' FROM DUEL", myTable);
if (!success)
    herp();
```

For more insight into pointers see my previous answer to a very similar question: [Pointer errors in the method of transmission(c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672816/pointer-errors-in-the-method-of-transmissionc/19673143#19673143)

Comment: thank you kfsone, thanks also for the tip on the first argument :D