# C++: Tree node not updating

Tags: c++

I am trying to update a node with a new value, but when I print out the node in another function, the old value is being displayed. I have also tried setting 'question' to the return value of updateTree(), in which it would return the new updated node, but that yields the same result.

```
void f(Node *n){//n is a pointer that has a string value with a left and right pointer. lets say that "n" right now is "duck"
   //do stuff....
   updateTree(n);
   cout << n->value;//prints out "duck" rather than the updated value..
}
  void updateTree(Node *question){

    string animal, q;
    cout << "Darn, I lost. What was is? ";
     getline(cin, animal);
     cout << "Enter a question that is true for a(n) " << animal << " and false for a(n) " << question->value << ": ";
     getline(cin, q);
     Node right(question->value, nullptr, nullptr);//the old animal ie "duck"
     Node left(animal, nullptr, nullptr);//the new animal
     question = new Node(q, &left, &right);//updated "n" ie "duck" to something else

  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer errors in the method of transmission(c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672816/pointer-errors-in-the-method-of-transmissionc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
void updateTree(Node *question) {
             // ^^^^^^ That's a copy of the pointer variable passed.
             //        Assignments will never affect the original pointer value                 
    // ...
    question = new Node(q, &left, &right);
}
```

sends the newly created `Node` to void, it's lost as soon that function leaves scope. You're operating on a copy of that pointer variable.

What you actually need is a ***reference*** that allows changing the original pointer:

```
void updateTree(Node*& question) {
                  // ^
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. If I reference the pointer and update it, will that parents pointer point to the new value? I'm coming from Java and it seems to me that by printing out the original parent of the pointer, it does not display the new value.